# Are htlatex (TeX4HT) and cleveref compatible?

Tags: tex4ht, cleveref, html, htlatex

Simple question:  When I use `cleveref` and `\Cref{}` or `\cref{}` I am able to compile the code and produce a PDF.  When I use `htlatex` I get `??` in place of what I expect would be the object name and section number.

Following a modified form of the the example MWE found  [How can I make \cref{foo,bar} from cleveref work with htlatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168251/how-can-i-make-creffoo-bar-from-cleveref-work-with-htlatex) as included below, I would like to figure out what the requirements to use `htlatex` and `cleveref` together are?  I was sure that in the last couple of weeks trying to get this to work that I have stumbled across successfully compiled html files that included the text and number expected by a `\cref{}` or `\Cref{}` command, but never in a stable reproducible format.

```
\documentclass{report}

\ifdefined\HCode
    \usepackage{tex4ht}
    \usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref}
\else 
    \usepackage{hyperref} 
\fi

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{cleveref}}

\begin{document}
    \section{\label{foo}foo}
    %\cref{bar,baz} - this won't compile but the problem is deeper rooted because cref alone doesn't work.
        %\protect\cref{foo}
        \cref{baz} follows \cref{bar}
    \section{bar}\label{bar}
    \section{baz}\label{baz}
\end{document}
```

I have also tried the example (slightly modified with solution incorporated) [How can I make amsthm and cleveref to work with htlatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167855/how-can-i-make-amsthm-and-cleveref-to-work-with-htlatex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{cleveref}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}
\begin{document}
\begin{rmk}\label{test}
Test content
\end{rmk}

See the test found in \cref{test}
\end{document}
```

So in collecting enough information to understand why this isn't working, I would like to know:

1. Is there a `cleveref` option similar to `\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref}` that should be used
2. Is there a known bug or compatibility problem - [Why does htlatex not work as expected?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194101/why-does-htlatex-not-work-as-expected)
3. Is there a command line option that can be added to `htlatex test.tex` that is fundamental and missing (I am suspicious of this possibility because of the reference to my second example.  If the solution here was to ensure `cleveref` is loaded last in the preamble, and my obvious issue of `??` appearing in place of actual references was present, then I am sure it would have been followed up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your example is unnecessarily complicated, this should work as well:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \section{foo}\label{foo}
    \cref{sec:bar,sec:baz} - this won't compile but the problem is deeper rooted because cref alone doesn't work.
        %\protect\cref{foo}
        \Cref{sec:baz} follows \cref{sec:bar} and \cref{foo}
    \section{bar}\label{sec:bar}
    \section{baz}\label{sec:baz}
\end{document}
```

now little bit technical description: the problem with `cleveref` and `tex4ht` is that `cleveref` creates internal reference with saved information about reference type. this information is saved in macro `\cref@currentlabel`, which is declared with `\protected@edef`. this means that it is defined only in current group, which doesn't cause problems with ordinary LaTeX, but under `tex4ht`, because of some redefinition, this macro is defined in group and is undefined later, when information is saved to the `aux` file. we need to replace `\protected@edef` with `\protected@xdef`, so the information is available outside of current group.

the solution is to make configuration file for `cleveref`, `cleveref.4ht`. this file is automatically included by `tex4ht` when `cleveref` is used:

```
\def\refstepcounter@noarg#1{%
  \cref@old@refstepcounter{#1}%
  \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@xdef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#1}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}
    }%
\def\refstepcounter@optarg[#1]#2{%
  \cref@old@refstepcounter{#2}%
  \cref@constructprefix{#2}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#2}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#2\endcsname\csname the#2\endcsname}}%
```

put file `cleveref.4ht` into directory with your document.

result:

[image]

Comment: Wow!  Wish I asked earlier, no way I would have come up with this on my own.  I am curious however why `\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{cleveref}}` or `\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}}` seem to be incompatible with the `cleveref.4ht` part of your solution.  Not really a big deal as it isn't hard to put the `\RequirePackage{cleveref}` at the end of my `cls` file.

Comment: @EngBIRD it isn't incompatible, it is just unnecessary. but if it has some deeper reason, you can use that

Comment: Thanks, I will keep in mind for future use that it should be compatible - something elsewhere in my massive class file must be the source of the problem with some unintended interaction as when I run with either of these two instructions I get the original failed `??`.  This particular problem is not worth isolating packages to determine which one.  Thanks again for the great solution!

Comment: @michal.h21 Might I suggest this be included in `tex4ht`?...  ;)

Comment: @gusbrs thanks for reminder, I've added this to the `tex4ht` sources

Comment: @michal.h21 It is I who thank you!

Comment: @EngBIRD Sorry, I don't understand how you resolved this issue? I tried to put `\RequirePackage{cleveref}` at the end of my `cls` file but the problem about `\eorem:syle` appears (I looked at `amsthm.4ht`. It seems to me that this is related to the order of loading different macros (some hacking of `\expandafter` depends on the order).

Comment: @Yai0Phah Can you confirm that you created the `cleveref.4ht` file in your current file directory? I can't confirm whether updates to tex4ht in the last 5 years have made this obsolete, but I never start a project without a local copy of this file.

Comment: @EngBIRD `cleveref.4ht` is already there in the latest TeXLive (a lot of improvement has been [made](https://www.tug.org/tex4ht/changelog.html)). Well, after rereading your post, it seems to me that I misunderstood your post and the example including `amsthm.4ht` is not what you are interested in (and you just referred to it to show the possibility of `\AtEndPreamble`)? I mostly have trouble with the conflict of `amsthm.4ht` and `cleveref` in tex4ht, which I thought that you have (temporarily) resolved by a trick of using `cls` file.