# Making hyperlinks working with cleveref and htlatex/TeX4HT

Tags: tex4ht, cleveref, htlatex, hyperlink

Following [Are htlatex (TeX4HT) and cleveref compatible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220288/are-htlatex-tex4ht-and-cleveref-compatible#) I am able to create cross-references with `cleveref` package with htlatex.

Still, these cross-references are not hyperlinked, while those created with usual `\ref{}` are.

Here is my test file

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % may use latin1 instead of utf8
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{testsection}
\label{testlabel}

Go to \cref{testlabel}

Go to \ref{testlabel}

\end{document}
```

and here is my output
[image: htlatex output]

Is there a way out?

Comment: check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220288/are-htlatex-tex4ht-and-cleveref-compatible

Comment: @MadyYuvi you suggested _exactly_ the same post that I linked in the description and that does **not** answer the problem!
As I said, I **do** have "go to section 1" in my output, but the problem here is that it is not hyperlinked: this is the problem!

Comment: Oops...sorry, I didn't notice that....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following version of `cleveref.4ht`:

```
% cleveref.4ht (2018-06-08-16:51), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2018 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2018-06-08-16:51}


\def\refstepcounter@noarg#1{%
  \cref@old@refstepcounter{#1}%
  \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@xdef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#1}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}
    }%
\def\refstepcounter@optarg[#1]#2{%
  \cref@old@refstepcounter{#2}%
  \cref@constructprefix{#2}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#2}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#2\endcsname\csname the#2\endcsname}}%

\ifdefined\@firstoffive\else%
  \def\@firstoffive#1#2#3#4#5{#1}
\fi
\def\:tempa#1#2{\bgroup%
  \def\rEfLiNK##1##2{\Link{##1}{}}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoffive\csname r@#2\endcsname{}{}{}{}{}%
  \o:@@@setcref:{#1}{#2}%
  \EndLink\egroup%
}%

\HLet\@@@setcref=\:tempa
\Hinput{cleveref}
\endinput
```

It patches the `\@@@setcref` command, which is used for the printing of the references. The patch executes the current reference, in order to get the link. Because of the reference structure used by `tex4ht` when the Hyperref package is loaded is a bit complicated, we need to use some tricks like the `\@firstofone` command etc. It works with and without Hyperref though.

The solution supports even multiple references in one `\cref` command, as shown in a modified example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % may use latin1 instead of utf8
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{testsection}
\label{testlabel}

Go to \cref{testlabel,secondsectioon}
\section{second}
\label{secondsectioon}

Go to \ref{testlabel}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

There are two different links used in `\cref`, as is visible from the HTML code:

```xml
 <h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1   </span> <a 
 id="x1-10001"></a>testsection</h3>
<!--l. 11--><p class="noindent" >Go to <a 
href="#x1-10001">sections 1</a><a 
href="#x1-20002"> and 2</a>
</p>
   <h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">2   </span> <a 
 id="x1-20002"></a>second</h3>
<!--l. 15--><p class="noindent" >Go to <a 
href="#x1-10001">1<!--tex4ht:ref: testlabel --></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Again, a wonderful answer from you....you are one of a great asset for TeX4ht users...

Comment: I just copied your code and I got this, that is not providing hyperlinks. Do you have any idea why?
```html
<h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1   </span> <a 
 id="x1-10001"></a>testsection</h3>
<!--l. 11--><p class="noindent" >Go to sections&#x00A0;1 and&#x00A0;2
   <h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">2   </span> <a 
 id="x1-20002"></a>second</h3>
<!--l. 15--><p class="noindent" >Go to <a 
href="#x1-10001">1<!--tex4ht:ref: testlabel --></a>
```

Comment: @DarioMangoni it seems like if the updated `cleveref.4ht` isn't loaded in your case. you can place it in the directory with the TeX file

Comment: @michal.h21 I copied from your text directly to assure that everything was exactly the same. I cleaned all the temporary files, I changed folder, I left only _test.tex_ and _cleveref.4ht_.
I may add this: I compile just with `htlatex test.tex` since I understand that `cleveref` will automatically load the same-name 4ht configuration file.
Nonetheless, I tried also `htlatex test.tex "cleveref"` and `htlatex test.tex "cleveref.4ht"` and also without double quotes, but it gives me error (says it can't find _cleveref.cfg_

Comment: @DarioMangoni when you use `htlatex filename.tex "cleveref"`, tex4ht tries to load `cleveref.cfg` file, which ends in error. the `cleveref.4ht` should be loaded automatically. I've tried it right now in a new directory and it works. Could you post the .log file somewhere?

Comment: Sure! You can find my files [here](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/7k01ka41ajh3z/cleveref_tmp).
I left all the intermediate files so you may have a deeper understanding of what is going on. And thanks for your help.
There is also the `.vscode/tasks.json` that tells how it is called the compiler.

Comment: @DarioMangoni you use fairly old TeX distribution, it is possible that Cleveref had been updated since then and my fix works only with the updated version.