# tex4ht problem when using amsmath, hyperref, and cleveref packages with report/book documentclass

Tags: hyperref, amsmath, tex4ht, cleveref, report

I am trying to convert my PhD dissertation (`\documentclass{report}`) from LaTeX to HTML using `make4ht`. It uses the `amsmath`, `hyperref`, and `cleveref` packages, which are causing a problem when used with `make4ht` and `report` or `book` `documentclass` (but not when using `article`). Note that it compiles successfully using `pdflatex`. Following is a minimal working example to show the error:

```
% If I use the article class below, then it compiles with make4ht.
% It does not compile with report and book classes, however.
\documentclass{report}

% If I comment out any one (!) of the following three, then make4ht compilation goes smoothly.
% FML if the following order is wrong.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

If I comment out any one of the `\usepackage` commands above, then `make4ht` compilation using `make4ht -u mwe.tex` works. When attempting to compile the MWE as shown with `make4ht`, however, I get an error. Following is the last part of the log file, which also shows the version of `cleveref` I have:

```
Package: cleveref 2018/02/08 v0.21.1 Intelligent cross-referencing
Package cleveref Info: `hyperref' support loaded on input line 2301.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cref on input line 2301.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Cref on input line 2301.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \crefrange on input line 2301.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Crefrange on input line 2301.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cpageref on input line 2301.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Cpageref on input line 2301.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cpagerefrange on input line 2301.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Cpagerefrange on input line 2301.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \labelcref on input line 2301.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \labelcpageref on input line 2301.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...esult \relax \else \cref@addtoreset
                                                  {parentequation}{\cref@res...
l.2885 }{}
          %  end of \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}
?
```

It appears this has something to do with equations/subequations and the following lines in [cleveref.dtx](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.dtx):

```
\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
  % I am skipping many lines here...
  \let\cref@old@endsubequations\endsubequations%
  \cref@resetby{equation}{\cref@result}%
  \ifx\cref@result\relax\else%
    \cref@addtoreset{parentequation}{\cref@result}%
  \fi%
  \renewenvironment{subequations}{%
  % I am skipping some lines here again...
}
```

Adding a basic `make4ht` `*.cfg` file does not help. Using `\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{cleveref}}` does not help either. I am guessing that something must be added/modified in the `cleveref.4ht` file that I picked up from [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475462/making-hyperlinks-working-with-cleveref-and-htlatex-tex4ht)), but I do not know how to go about this without digging in too deep. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is some deep package interaction, the stuff that is a nightmare to debug. You use both `hyperref` and `cleveref`. `cleveref` uses the following code to define the `\cref@addtoreset` macro:

```
\let\if@cref@hyperrefloaded\iffalse%
\global\let\cref@addtoreset\@addtoreset%

\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \@ifpackagewith{hyperref}{implicit=false}{%
    \let\if@cref@hyperrefloaded\iftrue%
    \PackageWarning{cleveref}{hyperref package loaded with
      implicit=false option - disabling cleveref's hyperref support.
      This situation is not supported by cleveref, and there's no guarantee
      anything will work. You're on your own!}%
  }{%
    \let\if@cref@hyperrefloaded\iftrue%
    \PackageInfo{cleveref}{`hyperref' support loaded}%
    \let\cref@addtoreset\HyOrg@addtoreset%
```

Important line is this one:

```
    \let\cref@addtoreset\HyOrg@addtoreset%
```

When you insert `\show\HyOrg@addtoreset` at that place, you can see that it is undefined. The reason for that is that `hyperref` package exit its loading early when it detect `tex4ht`, before `\HyOrg@addtoreset` is defined.

To fix that, we need to patch the package loading mechanism in TeX4ht and define `\HyOrg@addtoreset` before it is loaded. Package fixes are included in `usepackage.4ht`. The fix can look like this:

```
\def\:temp{cleveref}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\let\HyOrg@addtoreset\@addtoreset
\fi
```

The full `usepackage.4ht` file:

```
% usepackage.4ht (2020-04-15-14:52), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2003-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2020 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2020-04-15-14:52}

   \def\:temp{tex4ht}\ifx \:temp\@currname
   \:warning{\string\usepackage{tex4ht} again?}
   \def\:temp#1htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#2}}
\expandafter\:temp \@filelist htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty!*?: %
\ifx \:temp\empty  \else
   \:warning{if
    \string\RequirePackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} was
    used try instead, repectively,
    \string\RequirePackage{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage{hyperref}}
\fi

\fi
\gdef\a:usepackage{\use:package xr,xr-hyper,eso-pic,showframe,expl3,savetrees,cleveref,biblatex,xeCJK,polyglossia,fontspec,tikz,pdfbase,caption,graphics,xcolor,imakeidx,minted,fancyhdr,,!*?: }
\gdef\use:package#1,{%
   \if :#1:\def\:temp##1!*?: {}\else
      \def\:temp{#1}\ifx \@currname\:temp
             \def\:temp##1!*?: {\input usepackage.4ht  }%
      \else \let\:temp=\use:package \fi
   \fi \:temp}
\def\:temp{xr}\ifx \@currname\:temp
   \:AtEndOfPackage{\let\XR:\XR@
   \def\XR@[#1]#2{%
    \Configure{AtBeginDocument}{\XR:[#1]{#2}}{}}%
}

\fi
\def\:temp{cleveref}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\let\HyOrg@addtoreset\@addtoreset
\fi
\def\:temp{xr-hyper}\ifx \@currname\:temp
   \:AtEndOfPackage{\let\XR:\XR@
    \def\XR@[#1][#2]#3{%
      \AtBeginDocument{\XR:[#1][#2]{#3}}
    }%
}

\fi
\def\:temp{eso-pic}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AddToShipoutPicture{\@ifstar{}{}}
\let\AddToShipoutPictureBG\AddToShipoutPicture
\let\AddToShipoutPictureFG\AddToShipoutPicture
\fi
\def\:temp{showframe}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{showframe}
\fi
\def\:temp{expl3}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion%
\xenunidelblock{Latin-expl3}%
\:AtEndOfPackage{\xeuniuseblock{Latin-expl3}}
\fi
\fi
\def\:temp{savetrees}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{savetrees}
\fi
\def\:temp{biblatex}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \def\blx@mknoautolang{%
    \blx@lbxinput{\blx@languagename}%
    {}{}%
  }%
  \def\blx@lbxinput@iii#1#2{%
  \global\csundef{blx@lng@#2}%
  \:IfFileExists{#1.lbx}
    {\blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#1}{language '#2' -> '#1'}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@suffmaptried@#2}
      {}
      {\blx@warning@noline{%
          File '#1.lbx' not found!\MessageBreak
          Ignoring mapping '#2' -> '#1'}%
       \global\cslet{blx@suffmaptried@#2}\@empty}%
     \blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#2}{language '#2'}}}

}
\fi
\def\:temp{xeCJK}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{xeCJK}
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \RequirePackage{fontspec}
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\setCJKmainfont{o m o}{}
\let\setCJKsansfont\setCJKmainfont
\let\setCJKmonofont\setCJKmainfont

\DeclareDocumentCommand\setCJKfamilyfont {m o m }{}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\newCJKfontfamily {o m o m}{\expandafter\gdef\csname #2\endcsname{\relax}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\xeCJKsetup{m}{}
% }
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xeuniuseblock{CJK}
}
\fi
\def\:temp{polyglossia}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\ExplSyntaxOn
\:AtEndOfPackage{

\cs_set_eq:NN\orig_polyglossia@keys_define_lang:n\polyglossia@keys_define_lang:n
\cs_set_protected:Npn \polyglossia@keys_define_lang:n #1 {
  \orig_polyglossia@keys_define_lang:n{#1}
  \keys_define:nn {polyglossia}{
    #1 / direction
    .  code:n = {}
  }
}
\def\RequireBidi{}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\fi
\def\:temp{fontspec}\ifx \@currname\:temp
  \ifdefined\fontspec
    \:dontusepackage{fontspec}
  \else
    \input usepackage-fontspec.4ht
  \fi
\fi
\def\:temp{tikz}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
\let\use:tikzlibrary\usetikzlibrary
\def\find:externalize#1external#2\@nil{%
\if\relax#2\relax\else
  \let\tikz:externalize\tikzexternalize
  \renewcommand\tikzexternalize[1][]{\tikz:externalize[##1,mode=only graphics]}
    \tikzset{%
      tex4ht inc/.style={%
        /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
          \includegraphics[]{####1.pdf}%
        }%
      }
    }
    \tikzset{tex4ht inc}
  \fi
}
\append:defI\use@@tikzlibrary{\find:externalize##1external\@nil}%
}
\fi
\def\:temp{pdfbase}\ifx\@currname\:temp
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \let\old:outputpage\@outputpage
  \def\@outputpage{\old:outputpage{}}
}
\fi
\def\:temp{caption}\ifx\@currname\:temp
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \long\def\caption@If@Package@Loaded#1[#2]#3#4{}
}
\fi
\def\:temp{graphics}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \ifdefined\XeTeXversion
    \PassOptionsToPackage{dvips}{graphics}
  \fi
\fi
\def\:temp{xcolor}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \ifdefined\XeTeXversion
    \PassOptionsToPackage{dvips}{xcolor}
  \fi
\fi
\def\:temp{imakeidx}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \PassOptionsToPackage{noautomatic}{imakeidx}
\fi
\def\:temp{minted}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \:AtEndOfPackage{%
    \define@booleankey{minted@opt@g}{breaklines}{}{}{}%
  }
\fi
\def\:temp{fancyhdr}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \def\ps@fancy{}%
  }
\fi


\endinput
```

Your sample now compiles without errors.

I will update TeX4ht sources to include this fix, so it should be available in TL 2020 soon.

Comment: Is there any way to fix [the conflict with `amsthm` now](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491933/)?

Comment: @Yai0Phah I can try it again